# What grammar structure is "having + [verb]-ed"?

Tags: grammar

I asked [this question](http://www.usingenglish.com/forum/ask-teacher/179859-grammar-structure.html) on another site, but have not received any answers.  What grammar structures are these?

> Having finished his reading he went out for a stroll.
>
> She reproach me with having sent her to the Home.
>
> The old fellow fidgeted a bit. Then, “Well, I know I didn’t ought to have done it,”

I am interested in 'having done doing something' and *to have done* structures, like "having + [verb]-ed."  What is this grammatical structure called?

Comment: It's not clear exactly what you are asking. If you can't be more specific, I suspect there will soon be enough votes to close the question.

Comment: The first one is a simple preposed participial construction. The second is ungrammatical; it should be _for_ instead of _with_. The third is a novelistic device to avoid having to write _said_ repeatedly in reported conversation.

Comment: _Reproach with_ is grammatical in British English.

Comment: @JohnLawler: I think *with* is grammatical but conveys different meaning than *for*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This particular construction is known as a [perfect participle](http://www.learnenglish.de/grammar/participleperfect.htm). As the site indicates, it more or less expresses an action that has been completed.